# Find and replace text based on feature class attribute

Tags: arcpy

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days. It seems to be more programmatic than geospatial in nature, so I'm open to suggestions to redirect this elsewhere.

I have a text file representing a project file for another program. I'm trying to search that text file based on a feature class (or shapefile) with an ID field (`ATTR_1`) with elevation information (`ElevMeters`) and replace default terrain heights with heights pulled from the feature. I can't really search for the ID info alone because it appears numerous times throughout the project file. From my perspective, I have to search through the project to find lines with `$TERRAIN_HEIGHT :`, look three lines above to match `$PHOTO_NUM` with the equivalent `ATTR_1`, and then replace the `$TERRAIN_HEIGHT` value with `ElevMeters`.

I've gotten my script to property assign and print correct `ElevMeters` values for each `ATTR_1` found. I've been unable to get it to replace the `$TERRAIN_HEIGHT :` line properly. **It prints all new values at the end of the document rather than the line I thought I was directing it to.**

```
import os, arcpy

pdir = r"input directory path"
infile = r"input project file path"
infc = r"input feature class"
fields = ['ATTR_1', 'ElevMeters']

fpath = os.path.join(pdir, infile)
f = open(fpath, 'r+')
searchlines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "$TERRAIN_HEIGHT : " in line:
        print i #prints line number
        for l in searchlines[i-3:i-2:2]: #go up three lines, skip every other character
            print l #prints photo_num
            print line #prints original terrain_height
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, fields) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    if str(row[0]) in l:
                        newline = str(line)[:20] + str(row[1])
                        f.write(line.replace(line, newline))
f.close()
```

To prove that I'm grabbing values correctly, when I run this code:

```
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
if "$TERRAIN_HEIGHT : " in line:
    print i,
    for l in searchlines[i-3:i-2:2]:
        print l,
        print line,
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, fields) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if str(row[0]) in l:
                    newline = str(line)[:20] + str(row[1])
        print newline
```

I get an output that looks something like this, with line number, photo number, a default `$TERRAIN_HEIGHT :` of `650.000000` and correct new values underneath:

```
...
4153   $PHOTO_NUM : 60858
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 650.000000
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 446.301
4165   $PHOTO_NUM : 60859
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 650.000000
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 447.882
4181   $PHOTO_NUM : 60860
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 650.000000
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 448.934
4197   $PHOTO_NUM : 60861
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 650.000000
  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : 441.156
...
```

Comment: I don't believe 'f' knows which line it is meant to replace, so it appends to the end of the file. You need to loop through lines individually, as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-python

Comment: Will another ID ever occur in the three lines between an ID and  $TERRAIN_HEIGHT :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the trick I think. It looks for any line with $PHOTO_NUM, and when it finds one it checks three lines below with the use of the `linecache` module. If $TERRAIN_HEIGHT : is found three lines down, the script performs a cursor to find the replacement value, and calculates the index of the line to do the replacement in. Once this index is reached the replacement is made.

I haven't tested this out on data, so there may be a coding mistake or two.

Code:

```
import os, arcpy, linecache

pdir = r"input directory path"
infile = r"input project file path"
infc = r"input feature class"
fields = ['ATTR_1', 'ElevMeters']

newTxtfile = r"{New\text\file\full\path}"
nf = open(newTxtfile, "w")

di = {}

fpath = os.path.join(pdir, infile)
f = open(fpath, 'r')
searchlines = f.readlines()

cur_di = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cur_di[row[0]] = row[1]

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "$PHOTO_NUM" in line: #Look for all lines with a photo number
        thirdline = linecache.getline(fpath, i + 4) #Check third line down
        if "$TERRAIN_HEIGHT :" in thirdline: #Check if terrain height is three lines down
            for key in cur_di:
                if key in line:
                    di[thirdline] = cur_di[key]    
    if i in di: #if third line down from a match
        newline = str(line)[:20] + di[i] #replace value with new
        nf.write(newline) 
    else: #else if not third line down
        nf.write(line) #write line
f.close()
nf.close()
```

I hope this helps!

Edit: Whoops, I forgot that you had to write everything to a new text file. Code updated. You'll have to delete the old and rename the new if you don't want the second, updated text file.

Edit2: Updated the code to work regardless of whether or not another $PHOTO_NUM occurs in the three lines between a match $PHOTO_NUM and a $TERRAIN_HEIGHT, with use of a dictionary.

Comment: Note that you can increase the efficiency of this code with use of another dictionary. The second dictionary would have keys of your IDs and values of your elevations. Populate this dictionary with an initial cursor, and then you could skip all the nested cursors later in the code.

Comment: I made some minor adjustments (replaced textfile with fpath in line 19 and added () to f.close() and nf.close(). I also made open(fpath, 'r') rather than 'r+' since it's a new text file. Works great. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cool. I've updated my code with your fixes, as well as pulled out the searchcursor and made use of a second dictionary to speed things up. You might want to check that out. Hopefully I didn't break as much as I fixed.